# Bootstrap v2.3.1 vs v3.2.0: CSS / JS Issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on a rails application a while ago and adapted Bootstrap v2.3.1 and built the application on the framework. Now today, I brought in the newest versions of bootstrap (v3.2.0) through bower and implemented some features using it.

Due to the bootstrap upgrade, some styles implemented with the previous version got messy. (mainly css issues),
I fixed most of these issues by overriding the css to restore the original style, but Modal boxes (in particular) appear to be a pain to override.

The .hide class (and some others) do not seem to not be compatible between the 2 bootstrap versions. With bootstrap v2.3.1, my original modal box pop ups are hidden and displayed with:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden !important; 
  width: 0 !important; 
  height: 0 !important; 
  line-height: 0; 
  padding: 0 !important; 
  margin: 0 !important; 
}
```

and

```
.hide:after {
   visibility: hidden !important;
   width: 0 !important;
   height: 0 !important;
   line-height: 0 !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

and several similar classes.

Now using bootstrap v3.2.0, the modal boxes implemented in the previous style simply show a darkend backdrop with the modal boxes hidden.

I want to solve this issue without going in and overriding the css on every single modal box. 
Does anyone have any good solutions to this?

Perhaps an alternative class for modal boxes in the new bootstrap version?

Comment: .hide is deprecated, for the same as .hide use .hidden now. Are you using Bootstrap's modals? You don't need to add anything to them. I usually make my own class up, like hide-modal since Bootstrap sticks !important on .hidden and then jQuery obeys this !important. I am using Magnific Popup for modals -- inline, ajax, photos, galleries, iframe etc, it is seriously good.

Comment: ["Also, you should no longer apply `.hide` to `.modal` in your markup."](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 2.3.2 uses the following for modals:

```
 <div class="modal hide fade">
....
```

Bootstrap 3.2.0 uses:

```
<div class="modal fade">
....
```

Easy fix

Comment: Oh great. now the modal boxes appear but the sizes appear to drag in height to the bottom of the screen (the height attribute appears to be overriden, any ideas how to fix this without inline css)?

Comment: Post your html for you modal in your question.